# what is means reconstruct object or recreate object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` and following [Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python/2626364#2626364)

In the answer it says `__repr__`'s goal is to be unambiguous, I am confused what that really means. Another answer says: `__repr__`: representation of python object usually `eval` will convert it back to that object, so I have read that `eval` function let execute the python code in it.

Can someone please explain these terms in simple language:

- What is object reconstruction?
- What is `__repr__`?
- What is the connection between `eval` and `__repr__`?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a simple example will help clarify:

```
class Object:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Object({0.a!r}, {0.b!r})'.format(self)
```

This object has two parameters defined in `__init__` and a sensible `__repr__` method.

```
>>> o = Object(1, 2)
>>> repr(o)
'Object(1, 2)'
```

Note that the `__repr__` of our object now looks exactly like how we created it to begin with; it's legal Python code that supplies the same values. As the [data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) puts it:

> If at all possible, [`__repr__`] should look like a valid Python
>   expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same
>   value (given an appropriate environment).

That's where [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) comes in:

```
>>> x = eval(repr(o))
>>> x.a
1
>>> x.b
2
```

Because the representation is Python code, we can `eval`ulate it and get an object with the same values. This is *"reconstructing"* the original object `o`.

However, as pointed out in the comments, this is just an illustration and doesn't mean that you should rely on `repr(eval(x))` when trying to create a copy of `x`.

Comment: It would be useful to note "this is how you'd typically write `repr(..)` if writing one and definitely not how `repr(..)` and `eval` should be used". I remember someone using this combination to clone objects..